# SQL INSERT into MySQL table where column name includes an apostrophe

Tags: mysql, insert

Does anyone know how I can perform an SQL INSERT operation into a MySQL table where column names include apostrophes, for example:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (`id`, `Column'1`, `Column'2`) VALUES...
```

I have tried things like this but to no avail:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (`id`, `Column''1`, `Column''2`) VALUES...

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (`id`, `Column\'1`, `Column\'2`) VALUES...
```

Comment: I hope for your sake this is something you've been saddled with and it isn't a deliberate design decision.

Comment: I was curious more than anything, but I'm filtering out the apostrophes from the column names.

Comment: You will need to escape backticks in your table names, but those really don't belong there in the first place.

Comment: How to make this work?  `ALTER TABLE`  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just place backticks around the column name:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (`id`, `Column'1`, `Column'2`) VALUES...
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c2f0/1)

```
create table yourtable
(
  id int,
  col1 varchar(10),
  `col'2` varchar(10)
);

insert into yourtable (id, col1, `col'2`) values
(1, 'test', 'sdfsd'),
(1, 'test', 'gtet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name into a variable and use the character 39 for the apostrophe.

Example :

`L'oiseau` becomes :

```
Loiseau = 'L' + chr(39) + 'oiseau'
print(Loiseau)
```

=> `L'oiseau`

Comment: Can you explain that further? I don't think that `+` is the operator to concatenate strings in MySQL